# Generic repository pattern query execution

Tags: generics, repository

I am facing a problem on exection of query from entiry framework using repository pattern.

### This is the method from which the query will execute

```
   public tblUser AuthenticateUser(string userName, string password)        
    {            
       return _UnitOfWork.Repository<tblUser>().Get(x => x.UserName == userName && x.Password == password);
    }
```

### UnitofWork class for the repositories Initialization.

```
    public class UnitOfWork
    {
        private DbEntities _context = null;
        public Dictionary<Type, object> repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();


        public UnitOfWork()
        {
            _context = new DbEntities();
        }

        public GenericRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : class
        {
            if (repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(T)) == true)
            {
                return repositories[typeof(T)] as GenericRepository<T>;
            }
            GenericRepository<T> repo = new GenericRepository<T>(_context);
            repositories.Add(typeof(T), repo);
            return repo;
        }
    }
```

### Generic Repository class for Entity Operations

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{

    internal DbEntities Context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;      


    public GenericRepository(DbEntities context)
    {
        this.Context = context;
        this.DbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public TEntity Get(Func<TEntity, Boolean> where)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbSet;
        return query.Where(where).FirstOrDefault();
    }
 }
```

On the execution of the query, query created on the sql Server Profiler is

[sql profiler created query (Image:1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB82K.png)

As the query created on the sql Server Profiler the result fetching all the records from the database and after that the 
record is filtered on in memory of c#, But as the get method of the generic class the query should execute on the database server.

But when on the execution of query direct from entity framework,

```
        using (DbEntities context = new DbEntities())
        {
           return context.tblUsers.Where(x => x.UserName == userName && x.Password == password).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

In this case query created on the sql Server Profiler is

[sql profiler created query (Image:2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBRcu.png)

I am confused how to execute the query on repository pattern to execute the query and filtered the records on the database server like Image:2
Please help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `where` parameter is a function, which is C# code and must be executed in C#. It cannot be converted to SQL.

Instead, change the parameter type to an Expression:

```
public TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, Boolean>> where)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbSet;
    return query.Where(where).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

[Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) is a data-structure, which looks the same as a function (from the programmer's point of view). Entity Framework can convert that data-structure into SQL, and you get your query filtered.

Comment: Ohh that was the mistake i have done, now i have got this, Thnx for the solution buddy.....